# Get absolute Url in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

When I'm running my website with visual studio, its root url is: `http://localhost:4657`

I have strings containing paths like `~/Login.aspx` and I need to concatenate them so that the return will be `http://localhost:4657/Login.aspx`.

I can see a lot of ways to do this, but what is the right way?

Comment: Any way you've found that works is the 'right way'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [Page.ResolveUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx).

```
string url = Page.ResolveUrl("~/Login.aspx");
```

If you need a complete URL, say to email it or something, take a look at [this blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/154812.aspx).

Comment: ditto +1 for Rick Strahl's old blog post. I wish there were any updates on this on how to solve it on the newer ASP.Net versions if not necessarily ASP Core.

Answer (score 2):

How about Request.Url?
Url.Authority provides host name or Socket(IPAddress:PortNo) and segments provide other parts of URL. 
Just omit the LAST segment as it contains the current page's name. Hence i-1*.

```
    string myurl = "http://"+Request.Url.Authority;
    for(int i=0;i<Request.Url.Segments.Length-1;i++)
    {
        myurl = myurl + Request.Url.Segments[i];
    }
    myurl = myurl + "login.aspx";
    Response.Redirect(myurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use

```
var baseUri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, "/");
```