# Getting current directory in .NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, directory, filepath

So I have a web project, and I'm trying to get the root directory of the website using the c# method `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`.  I don't want to be using a static path as the file locations will be changing in the future.  This method is running in my imageProcess.aspx.cs file, but where I thought it would return:

```
C:\Users\tcbl\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ModelMonitoring\ModelMonitoring\imageProcess.aspx.cs
```

I'm instead getting:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening and what a possible solution might be? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6041332/465053) which talks about .Net application execution paths in general.

Comment: Another post which talks about [server map paths in web applications in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/275781/465053)

Answer (score 238, accepted):

The current directory is a system-level feature; it returns the directory that the server was launched from.  It has nothing to do with the website.

You want `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath`.

If you're in an HTTP request, you can also call `Server.MapPath("~/Whatever")`.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually looking for `HttpRuntime.BinDirectory`, but that was easy to determine in the debugger, once I tried what you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: If I use `Server.MapPath("~Whatever") and the IIS site is hosted in http://myserver. I get a C:\\somefolder\Whatever, rather than http://myserver/Whatever folder.

Comment: @Si8: Yes; that's what `Server.MapPath` does.  You want http://stackoverflow.com/q/5823847/34397

Comment: In case you are unfamiliar with .NET assemblies (or are in Immediate Window), the full commands are `System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` and `System.Web.HttpRuntime.HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~")`

Comment: @testpattern `HttpContext` is  `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~")`, not have `HttpRuntime`

Comment: In a static method, use HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~") instead.

Answer (score 125):

Use this code:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~")
```

Detailed Reference:

`Server.MapPath` specifies the relative or virtual path to map to a physical directory.

- `Server.MapPath(".")` returns the current physical directory of the
  file (e.g. aspx) being executed
- `Server.MapPath("..")` returns the parent directory
- `Server.MapPath("~")` returns the physical path to the root of the
  application
- `Server.MapPath("/")` returns the physical path to the root of the
  domain name (is not necessarily the same as the root of the
  application)

An example:

Let's say you pointed a web site application (http://www.example.com/) to

```
C:\Inetpub\wwwroot
```

and installed your shop application (sub web as virtual directory in IIS, marked as application) in

```
D:\WebApps\shop
```

For example, if you call `Server.MapPath` in following request:

```
http://www.example.com/shop/products/GetProduct.aspx?id=2342
```

then:

```
Server.MapPath(".") returns D:\WebApps\shop\products
Server.MapPath("..") returns D:\WebApps\shop
Server.MapPath("~") returns D:\WebApps\shop
Server.MapPath("/") returns C:\Inetpub\wwwroot
Server.MapPath("/shop") returns D:\WebApps\shop
```

If Path starts with either a forward (/) or backward slash (), the `MapPath` method returns a path as if Path were a full, virtual path.

If Path doesn't start with a slash, the `MapPath` method returns a path relative to the directory of the request being processed.

*Note: in C#, @ is the verbatim literal string operator meaning that the string should be used "as is" and not be processed for escape sequences.*

Footnotes

`Server.MapPath(null)` and `Server.MapPath("")` will produce this effect too.

Comment: Perfect copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath#275791

Comment: @GGO Good link! Following the links, I ended up doing `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~")` instead, which works great, with no dependency on `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`

Answer (score 8):

For dot net 6 I use:

```
AppContext.BaseDirectory
```

Cool thing about that is that it will be the same on asp.net and also on a console application.

Comment: string baseDirectory = AppContext.BaseDirectory;

// it returns the bin path e.g. D:\WebMVCApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\