# How to send multiple formdata using ajax and each from data have multiple images in asp.net core web app

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-ajax, razor-pages, asp.net-core-7.0

How to send multiple formdata using ajax and each from data have multiple images in asp.net core web app and data asp.net core web api.
I need to save product variants with variant images.

I am able to save multiple variant without images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple example based on your description, it should help you.

My IndexModel:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public class TestModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile FormFiles { get; set; }
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public List<TestModel> TestModels { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return Page();
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml(Suppose I want to pass two objects of type `TestModel`):

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf
    
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
        string GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()
        {
            return Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(Model.HttpContext).RequestToken;
        }
}

<div>
    @for(var i = 0; i < 2 ; i++){
        <div class="group">
            <div>
               Id: <input class="id" type="number" />
            </div>
            <div>
                Name: <input class="name" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div>
                FormFiles: <input class="files" type="file" />
            </div>
        </div>
        
    }
    <div>
        <input value="Upload" type="submit" id="Upload" />
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $("#Upload").click(function (e) {
        var formdata = new FormData();
        for (var i = 0; i < $(".group").length; i++) {
            formdata.append("TestModels[" + i + "].Id", $(".group").find(".id")[i].value);
            formdata.append("TestModels[" + i + "].Name", $(".group").find(".name")[i].value);
            formdata.append("TestModels[" + i + "].FormFiles", $(".group").find(".files")[i].files[0]);
        }

        $.ajax({
                method: "post",
                url: "/",
                headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": '@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()' },
                data: formdata,
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
            });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

I can successfully receive formData:
[image]

Also I'm not sure how you do the saving, but if you want to save the picture to the database, you can refer to my steps below.

My Database Table:

[image]

Convert the image to byte and store it in the database:

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    var model = new TestModel();
    foreach (var item in TestModels)
    { 
        model.Id = item.Id;
        model.Name = item.Name;
        if (item.FormFiles != null)
        {
            if (item.FormFiles.Length > 0)
            {
                byte[] p1 = null;
                using (var fs1 = item.FormFiles.OpenReadStream())
                    using (var ms1 = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        fs1.CopyTo(ms1);
                        p1 = ms1.ToArray();
                    }
                    model.ImageData = p1;
            }
        }
        _context.TestModel.Add(model);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    return Page();
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

If you want to display the image on the page, you can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64905575/display-image-from-database-in-asp-net-core-3-1).

If you have multiple images and the number is uncertain, and you want to save them in the database, you can create a table for the image data and match it with `TestModelId`. For example:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ImageData> FormFiles { get; set; }
}

public class ImageData
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TestModelId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile FormFiles { get; set; }
}
```