# Read an excel file in ASP.NET Core hosted in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core

I have an endpoint that should return a value from an excel file.

On localhost this works by enabling `UseStaticFiles` middleware using this code, and adding excel file into the `Resources` folder:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
   FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
       Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "Resources")),
   RequestPath = "/Resources"
});
```

However when I publish it in the Azure hosting it shows this error and I cannot acces my application nor this excel file.
[image]

After I remove the `UseStaticFiles` middleware, application works well except for the missing excel file.

So how should I publish and access this file in the Azure environment?

Comment: Read this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0 . You have either a permission problem if the server is Linux or a "CopyAlways" missing if it is windows. But read the documentation step by step and for sure you will figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The `UseStaticFiles` method only, and I [quote](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.staticfileextensions.usestaticfiles?view=aspnetcore-6.0), "Enables static file serving". This does *not* enable you to return a value from a specific cell in an Excel file.

If you're looking for serving static files you could for instance have a look at putting the file in Azure Storage and using the desired [public access level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-configure?tabs=portal#about-anonymous-public-read-access).

If you're looking to *read* from an Excel file, you might want to have a look at a way to do so that does not require Interop since you will not have Excel available on an App Service.

On option would be to use [the OpenXML XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk).

> The SDK is built on the **System.IO.Packaging** API and provides strongly-typed classes to manipulate documents that adhere to the Office Open XML File Formats specification.
>
> [...]
>
> The Open XML file formats are useful for developers because they are an open standard and are based on well-known technologies: ZIP and XML.

Another would be an open source solution like [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) which is a wrapper around OpenXML making working with them easier.

> ClosedXML is a .NET library for reading, manipulating and writing Excel 2007+ (.xlsx, .xlsm) files. It aims to provide an intuitive and user-friendly interface to dealing with the underlying OpenXML API.

Comment: The problem was accessing excel file when application is hosted in Azure. I will check out Azure Storage, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I combined [Clean Windows Azure Website](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17552723/8483576) and [Accessing wwwroot folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64867695/8483576) to come up with the solution.

No middleware is required, just by using `IWebHostEnvironment` service I could access needed excel file, which is now based in the `wwwroot/Resources/` directory within my project.

```
private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

public ProjectService(IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   _env = env;
}

public double GetExcelValue() 
{
   string excelFilePath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Resources/file.xlsx");

   (...)
}
```