# Can access private file in localhost, but not in production

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core, io

I'm writing an ASP.NET Core app, and I'm trying to use a file's path without exposing it to the web. I set it to copy to output directory, so it loads when I test it on localhost, but it gives me an error when published to the web:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This is the code that generates the path:

```
Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Config", "filename.p12");
```

I've also tried

```
Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Config", "filename.p12");
```

I'm guessing `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` and `Environment.CurrentDirectory` point to a different location when published? Or `filename.p12`'s 'Copy to Output Directory' property doesn't carry over to the published version?

EDIT:

I also tried:

```
Path.Combine(environment.ContentRootPath, "Config", "file.p12");
```

Where `environment` is an `IHostEnvironment`, to the same effect. I'm getting the feeling that the file isn't being copied over into the published version. So, I changed the filename I put in this question to be `file.p12` instead of `file.txt`, which is what I originally put it as, in case it doesn't copy over that type of file for security reasons.

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951599/getting-current-directory-in-net-web-application

Comment: Are you deploying to a Linux environment?

Comment: @RoarS. How can I tell? I think I'm deploying to a Windows environment, since I'm deploying to Microsoft Azure. I'm deploying from a Mac, if that changes anything.

Comment: With Azure you can use Kudu and inspect if the file is present in the location

Comment: I'm usually working with AWS, tested Azure once, please bear over me if I'm wrong. I believe Azure is all Linux unless you have some special setup with dedicated VMs. Anyway, you'll need to find out.

Answer (score 0):

The error said `The system cannot find the file specified.`, but the file was actually there. I was actually missing the `X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet` flag when I read the .p12 file. I think the reason it didn't work in production was that the server's current user didn't own the file, so I needed to specify that the machine owns it with that flag.